# For loop with exception

Tags: java, for-loop

how do you write a `for loop` with an exception. I don't really want to use arrays. For example, how do I write a for loop that prints a count from 1 to 10 missing out 5?

This following code:

```
class ForDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
         for(int i=1; i<11; i++){
              System.out.println("Count is: " + i);
         }
    }
}
```

will output:

```
Count is: 1
Count is: 2
Count is: 3
Count is: 4
Count is: 5
Count is: 6
Count is: 7
Count is: 8
Count is: 9
Count is: 10
```

How do I make it output: (missing out 5)?

```
Count is: 1
Count is: 2
Count is: 3
Count is: 4
Count is: 6
Count is: 7
Count is: 8
Count is: 9
Count is: 10
```

Comment: Are you asking for an `if` statement?

Comment: what do you mean? `if i=5` do not print?

Comment: Well, doesn't that sound like a good approach? You need to think for yourself.

Comment: `IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).filter(i -> i != 5).forEach(i -> System.out.println("Count is: " + i););`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you tried? Here's one possible solution:

```
class ForDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
         for(int i=1; i<11; i++){
              if(i != 5){
                  System.out.println("Count is: " + i);
              }
         }
    }
}
```

I added a check in there: `if(i != 5)` which executes the code inside only if the condition is true (ie: i is not 5). This is available in most if not all programming languages.